# Taylor Series $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{(1+2x+3y)^2}$ at the point (0,0)

Tags: derivatives, taylor-expansion

I found this exercise rather important for myself but I'm a bit struggling and can't solve it. So can anyone help me?

Write a function $$f(x,y)=\frac{1}{(1+2x+3y)^2}$$ in a Taylor Series at the point $(0,0)$.
I can calculate all of these derivatives and points, but I need to find a nice formula.

Comment: Geometrically expand .... How many terms do you want ?

Comment: $$f(x,y)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n(n+1)\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}(2x)^k(3y)^{n-k}=\sum_{i,j=0}^\infty(-1)^{i+j}(i+j+1){i+j\choose i}2^i3^jx^iy^j$$

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how "nice" this formula in $\Bbb{R}^2$ is, but it's compact

$$
f(x,y)=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\Big\{\frac{1}{j!}\big[(x-x_0)\frac{\partial }{\partial x}+(y-y_0)\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\big]^jf(x,y)\Big\}_{x_0,y_0}
$$

In your case since $x_0=y_0=0$, this would actually simplify to

$$
f(x,y)=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\Big\{\frac{1}{j!}\big[x\frac{\partial }{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\big]^jf(x,y)\Big\}_{0,0}
$$

Comment: Unless you're up for some torture, I'd truncate the series after the 2nd or third derivative :-)

Answer (score 0):

First of all note that
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left(-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1+2x+3y}\right)=\frac{1}{(1+2x+3y)^2}
$$
and that, expanding using the geometric series we have
$$
\frac{1}{1+2x+3y}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n(2x+3y)^n
$$
so that
$$
\frac{1}{(1+2x+3y)^2}=\frac{d}{dx}\left(-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1+2x+3y}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}n(2x+3y)^{n-1}
$$
This is not exactly the Taylor series, but you can expand, for each term of the series, by the binomial theorem
$$
(2x+3y)^{n-1}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\pmatrix{n-1 \\ k}(2x)^k(3y)^{n-1-k}
$$